# Where to play online Bughouse Chess

Tags: online-chess, bughouse

As far as I can tell the main sites I use like chess.com, lichess.com, and chess24.com do not support bughouse. Is there a popular place to play online somewhere? It would also like to have the ability to play on iOS. Thanks.

Comment: For your information as well, lichess is planning on adding bughouse in the future.

See this developer site: http://bughousetest.com

Comment: @TheHonestAtheist Cool! Last I heard this was not planned for lichess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use one of the fics interfaces. Freechess.org

Answer (score 12):

Now you can play bughouse  at [Chess.com](http://chess.com) (for free). You can read [this article to get help](https://www.chess.com/article/view/how-to-play-variants-on-chess-com#bughouse).

Answer (score 1):

You can play on online1.eu where is possible to play slower bughouse also. There You play using web browser, so You can play from any PC, notebook, tablet, iPod etc. with any operating system like windows, linux, android, or   iOS.

Answer (score 1):

FICS(freechess.org) and ICC(chessclub.com)

Answer (score 0):

Android mobile app for bughouse online game with your friends: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.mail.park.bughouse

Answer (score 0):

chess.com has bughouse; it works quite well.

I know lichess is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new small specialized bughouse chess server which has unique lag double board compensator options on onlinea.org , actually runned node http://onlinea.eu